# Insert string first form and it show second form after 5 times insertion it print first time inserted string

Tags: c#

I want that when I press one button then form 2 appeared which I do.
but I have problem that I insert string in textbox when I insert fifth time it shows first time inserted string. but I don't do it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = new string(9);
    str = Username.Text;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
    }

    Form3 obj = new Form3(Username.Text);
    this.Hide();
    obj.Show();
}
```

it is my code.

Comment: When you write `new Form3` you always pass `Username.Text` so it will always have that value.

Comment: but when i pass fifth time value it not show fifth value it show first time inserted value

Comment: new string(9) will not even compile. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i wanted that when user click on first time on first form button then it goes to next form where we have 3 textbox and one button and then when user insert a stirng in any one textbox then it should see it on third form where we have only one textbox and one button and when he press button 4 times he see first time inserted string.